# how to float glyiphicons to the right inline

Tags: html, css

this puts the glyphicons right next to "Some File"

```
<li>
    <h5>Some File <a href="info"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i></a>  <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></i></a></h5>
</li>
```

how would I float the glyphicons to the right?

Comment: it is in bootstrap https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/typography/

Comment: Huh. I don't remember ever seeing it, IIRC headers ended at level 4. Learn something new everyday.

Comment: what is your mean of `right inline`?

Comment: `class='pull-right'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very hard to know what you're looking for without giving us a visual example when there is so little context on your question. Even though it's hard to know for sure, I believe this is what you're looking for.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>
  <li>
      <h5>Some File <span class="pull-right"><a href="info"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></i></a></span></h5>
  </li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```